# ASP.NET MVC model binder doesn't bind my ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

This is my viewModel , which i am binding to the view.

```
public class EmployeeMasterViewModel
{
    public EmployeeViewModel Employee { get; set; }
    public List<SkillViewModel> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

The `Employee` property is binded successfully and all it properties are getting filled
but this is the problem , `Skills` property ,which is list of `SkillViewModel`,

```
public class SkillViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
}
```

`Skills.Count` is 0, when the form is submitted

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Skills.Count; i++)
{
        SkillViewModel skill = Model.Skills[i];
        string id = skill.Id + "-" + String.Join("-", skill.SkillName.Split(new[] { " " },             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        <tr id="@id">

            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.Skills[i].Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.Skills[i].SkillName)
                @skill.SkillName
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="javascript:deleteSkill('@id')">
                    <span class="label label-sm label-danger">
                        Delete
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CanCreateEmployee = Right.CanCreateEmployee;
        ViewBag.Skills = Common.GetSkills();

        var viewModel = new EmployeeMasterViewModel();
        var employee = new EmployeeViewModel
        {
            Departments = Common.GetDepartments(),
            Designations = Common.GetDesignations(),
            Grades = Common.GetGrades(),
            MaritalStatuses = Common.GetMaritalStatuses(),
            Genders = Common.GetGenders(),
        };

        viewModel.Skills = new List<SkillViewModel>();
        viewModel.Skills.Add(new SkillViewModel
        {
            Id = 1,
            SkillName = "Test Driven Developement"
        });

        viewModel.Employee = employee;

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

POST Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EmployeeMasterViewModel viewModel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (!Right.CanCreateEmployee)
        {
            Session["ErrorNotify"] = "You don't have permission to add new employee";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        viewModel.Employee.Departments = Common.GetDepartments();
        viewModel.Employee.Designations = Common.GetDesignations();
        viewModel.Employee.Grades = Common.GetGrades();
        viewModel.Employee.MaritalStatuses = Common.GetMaritalStatuses();
        viewModel.Employee.Genders = Common.GetGenders();
        viewModel.Skills = _model.GetEmployeeSkills();
        ViewBag.Skills = Common.GetSkills();
        ViewBag.CanCreateEmployee = Right.CanCreateEmployee;

        if (!CheckErrors(viewModel))
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        string image = Common.ImageUpload(file);
        if (image == "0")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ImageTypeError", "Image type not supported");
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        viewModel.Employee.ImgPath = image;
        _model.Insert(viewModel.Employee);

        Session["SuccessNotify"] = "Employee is successfully registered";

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: can you post your action method too?

Comment: If your View doesn't have the proper `@model` statement, if your action doesn't return with a `View(model)`, there's no viewmodel for the view to bind to. Post your action and your view. BTW, when you define a model, it's available as the `Model` variable. Where does `Skills` come from?

Comment: Check the `ModelState.IsValid` and `Errors` Collection for more diagnostic information.

Comment: Mario - The view file is very long

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos - Yeah of course , I have defined @model statement in view as well and the GET action is also returning View(myEmployeeMasterViewModel)

Comment: `Skills.Count is 0, when the form is submitted` do you really mean when submitted or when the view is rendered?

Comment: When the form is submitted , I see that List<skillViewModel> is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue, but my attempt is working fine.

**View Code**

```
@model SO.Controllers.EmployeeMasterViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee.EmployeeName);
    <input data-val="true" name="Skills[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input name="Skills[0].SkillName" type="hidden" value="Test Driven Developement">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new EmployeeMasterViewModel();
        vm.Employee = new EmployeeViewModel();
        vm.Skills = new List<SkillViewModel>();

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(EmployeeMasterViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

When I submitted the form, all of the data was passed correctly, including the skills data. Maybe you can use this answer as a reference to help you?

Comment: I have also done the same way and i have a code which is working fine for other business entities and it is written same as mentioned in question.

Comment: Actually , I was having a Dropdown with same name as Skills , which was conflicting with my List<SkillViewModel> Skills . Yeah , It was silly mistake